# ¿Es correcto decir "esto no tiene sentido"?

Tags: traducción

Es muy común la frase en inglés "this does not make any sense" para indicar que algo es ilógico o incoherente.

La pregunta es, es correcto decir "esto no tiene sentido" para indicar lo mismo, o es un mal uso del español y la frase existe como una traducción literal y por la influencia del idioma inglés?

Comment: No es una traducción literal del inglés, literalmente sería "eso no hace sentido".

Comment: Es la forma **correcta** de decirlo, si.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[En la entrada del DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/sentido), en sus acepciones 7 y 8 no habla del origen, pero sí de ese mismo significado:

> 7. *m.* Razón de ser, finalidad. *Su conducta carecía de sentido.*
>
> 8. *m.* Significación cabal de una proposición o cláusula. *Esta proposición no tiene sentido.*

Del verbo sentir indica que viene del latín.

En el diccionario inglés [Merrian Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sense):

> Origin of SENSE
> Middle English, from Anglo-French or Latin; Anglo-French sen, sens sensation, feeling, mechanism of perception, meaning, from Latin sensus, from sentire to perceive, feel; perhaps akin to Old High German sinnan to go, strive, Old English *sith* journey.
> First Known Use: 14th century.

Ahora habría que mirar en obras de Violante de Aragón y otros anteriores, para ver si ya se utilizaba en el español de esa época la palabra sentido. Mi opinión (especulativa) es que tienen la misma raíz latina y que el uso en español no depende del uso en inglés.

Answer (score 0):

I would say: "esto es *sin* sentido." This is *non*sense.

Comment: ¿En qué país se usa esa expresión?, es muy rara para mi!

Comment: @jachguate: In parts of Latin America. It is a favorite expression of a Peruvian friend of mine.

Comment: Diría que esa expresión no es de uso generalizado y quizás podría decirse que es un regionalismo. He viajado por distintos paises de habla hispana y no recuerdo haberla escuchado hasta ahora, a diferencia de _esto no tiene sentido_ que si se usa habitualmente y es entendida por todos.

Comment: En España se usa a veces el sustantivo "[sinsentido](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=sinsentido)". En ese caso, sería "esto es un sinsentido".

Comment: @MikMik +1 También en Argentina. Pero "esto no tiene sentido" es más natural, normalmente.

Comment: @MikMik esa experesión si que la he escuchado y es de uso más o menos común aquí también.